# Creating a search bar with CSS (button not attached to search box)

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to create a search-bar with CSS and came across two issues:

1. My button has this unwanted blue gap on the right side (this is because I tried to add a arrow to stick out of the left).

   I have tried different methods to get rid of the large area of blue, but i do not have enough experience to figure out why this is happening.
2. The search button is not meeting with the bar on the left side of the button, it has a gap.

If anyone has an idea to the cause please mention it.

This is my code:

```css
form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.search {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
  border: 1.5px solid #dbdbdb;
  width: 100px;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 6.5px 15px;
  left: -8px;
  border: 2px solid #207cca;
  background-color: #207cca;
  color: #fafafa;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #207cca;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* For WebKit browsers */
  color: #dd3333;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  /* For Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: #dd3333;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  /* For Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: #dd3333;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* For Internet Explorer 10+ */
  color: #dd3333;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*bar arrow-main*/

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  background: #207cca;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  left: -8 px;
}
.arrow:after {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: rbga(32, 124, 202, 0);
  border-right-color: #207cca;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="search" required="required" />
  <span class="arrow"><input type="button" value="Search" class= "button"/></span>
</form>
```

Here is [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/x2m3911x/44/) too.

Comment: Ps I got tried  to "use the code toolbar" to post JSFiddle links (got an error). You will have to copy and paste

Comment: By the way, that error is there for a reason... It tries to help you add code to your question so that it is not downvoted and closed. It's not simply meant to be ignored. I would suggest that you read [how to better ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks "Anonymous" for the constructive input, I read your guide, and will be on my way to "Asking better questions".

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following and see if it solves your problem. The biggest issue was that the `span` was wrapping the `button`
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/67nsk349/1/)

HTML:

```
<form >
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class= "search"  required>                           
<span class="arrow"></span><input type="button" value="Search" class= "button">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
width:500px;
margin:50px auto;
}
.search {
padding:8px 15px;
background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
border:1.5px solid #dbdbdb;
width:100px;
}
.button {
position:relative;
padding:6.5px 15px;
border:2px solid #207cca;
background-color:#207cca;
color:#fafafa;
}
.button:hover  {
background-color:#fafafa;
color:#207cca;
}
.arrow {
position:relative;
background:#207cca;
padding:;
margin-left:-5px;
}
.arrow:after {
right:100%;
top:50%;
border:solid transparent;
content: " ";
height:0;
width:0;
position: absolute;
border-color:rbga(32, 124, 202, 0);
border-right-color:#207cca;
border-width:10px;
margin-top:-7px;
}
```